# Using a recursive method to return an inorder string in java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, inorder

I want to make an in order transversal of a binary tree. I made this method:

```
public String inorder()
    {
        String inorder = "";
        return recrInorder(this.root, inorder);
    }
```

then i have a helper method:

```
private String recrInorder(Node curr,String string)
    {
        if(curr == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        //Go through left
        recrInorder(curr.getLeft(), string);
        string = string + curr.getData() + ", ";
        //Go through right
        recrInorder(curr.getRight(), string);
        return string;
    }
```

This will only print the root, i want the whole list printed.

Answer (score 3):

In Java parameters are passed by value for object reference so assigning new value to your input parameter named `string` will not change its value outside of that function.

You need to change your code like this

```
private String recrInorder(Node curr,String string)
{
    if(curr == null)
    {
        return string; // preserve previously calculated value
    }
    //Go through left
    string = recrInorder(curr.getLeft(), string);
    string = string + curr.getData() + ", ";
    //Go through right
    string = recrInorder(curr.getRight(), string);
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```java
public String inorder() {
    return recrInorder(this.root);
}
```

```java
private String recrInorder(Node curr) {
    if (curr == null) return "";
    return recrInorder(curr.getLeft()) + curr.getData() + ", " + rectInorder(curr.getRight());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a `parent`, `left` child, and `right` child relationship, the traversal of the tree is dependent on when you `visit` the parent and access the String value.

Given the `root` of the tree call it as follows:

```
    String s =  traverse(root, "");
    System.out.println(s);
```

```
    public static String traverse(Node n, String s) {
        if (n == null) {
            return s;
        }
        // s += n.value;  // uncomment this assignment for preorder traversal
        s = traverse(n.left,s);
        // s += n.value;  // uncomment this assignment for inorder traversal
        s = traverse(n.right,s);
        // s += n.value;  // uncomment this assignment for postorder traversal
        return s;
    }
```

So in your method, you could pass a flag or `enum` and caveat the assignment based on that value, thus adapting your method to any traversal.